# I have proved that $\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac{2}{n^2}$ But I don't know how one came up with it

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I have proved by induction that the Statement above is true

Here is my proof:

Inductionbase: $\frac{2!}{2^2}=\frac{2}{4}$

Inductionstep:$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\frac{n+1}{n+1}\overset{(n+1>n)}{\leq}\frac{n!}{n^n}\overset{\text{IH}}{\leq}\frac{2}{n^2}$

But I still don't understand why my proof is valid, why it makes sense. For me it is just a Formula, can somebody explainme how someone came up with the idea that:

$$\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac{2}{n^2},\forall n\geq 2$$

Comment: This proof isn't quite valid. On the induction step, you would need to show that $$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \le \frac{2}{(n+1)^2},$$ but instead you showed that $$\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \le \frac{2}{n^2}.$$ Also, this is a slightly confusing question: you say you came up with this proof, and then you're asking us to explain how someone would come up with it? Well *you* came up with it, how did you do it?

Comment: In the textbook one wrote without further explainations that $\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac{2}{n^2}$. I have tried to prove the Statement and thought I succeeded but I did not understand how one came up with the inequality by Looking at the fraction $\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot … n}{n\cdot n \cdot … n}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would write the inequality in the form
$$n!\le 2\cdot n^{n-2}$$

Comment: I understand: $n!=n\cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) … 2 \cdot 1$. And because $n\geq 2$ one can substitute the term $n \cdot (n-1) \cdot (n-2) … 3$ with $n^{n-2}$. And then I just have to put it in the Formula.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is invalid, because you have to show that

> if $\dfrac{n!}{n^n}\le\dfrac{2}{n^2}$, then $\dfrac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\le\dfrac{2}{(n+1)^2}$

Now
$$
\frac{(n+1)!}{(n+1)^{n}}=\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}=\frac{n!}{n^n}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}\le
\dfrac{2}{n^2}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}
$$
by the induction hypothesis.

You can finish by proving that, for $n\ge2$,
$$
\dfrac{2}{n^2}\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}\le\dfrac{2}{(n+1)^2}
$$
that's equivalent to
$$
\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n}}\le\dfrac{n^2}{(n+1)^2}
$$
or, as well, to
$$
\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n-2}\le1
$$
which follows from $n/(n+1)<1$: if $0<x<1$, then $x^k<1$, for $k\ge1$ (easy induction).

Since the proof only holds for $n\ge2$, you need to prove *two* base steps, for $n=1$ and $n=2$. Since
$$
\frac{1!}{1^1}\le\frac{2}{1^2}
\qquad
\frac{2!}{2^2}\le\frac{2}{2^2}
$$
you're done.